# Combine .each div heights

Tags: jquery, each

I am getting the height of each div with class="divHeight".

```
$.each($('.divHeight'), function() {
var eachDivHeight = $(this).height();   
console.log(eachDivHeight);
});
```

However, I cant figure out how to combine the values. In the console I get two numbers back (311, 17). How do I add the values that .each finds? Are those in an array?

My final code:

```
var totalHeight = 0;
$.each($('.divHeight'), function() {
 var eachDivHeight = $(this).outerHeight(true);
 totalHeight += eachDivHeight;
 $("#personDetailsView").css("height",totalHeight); 
 });
```

Note I had to use outerHeight(true) to account for margin on one of the div heights....that was a pain to figure out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have a variable defined outside of each that you used as running total.

```
var totalHeight = 0;
$.each($('.divHeight'), function() {
 var eachDivHeight = $(this).height();
 totalHeight += eachDivHeight;
 console.log(eachDivHeight);
});
console.log(totalHeight);
```

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kExCG/)**

Comment: @Anthony - It is short hand for `totalHeight = totalHeight + eachDivHeight;`. Its name is the [Addition Assignment Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/w2xk8y0c(v=vs.94).aspx).